# How to make SlateJS editor look like a MUI TextField?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slatejs

I am using `slate-react` in an app based on Material Design, using MUI.

What I want is for the Slate editor to look like an MUI TextField -- essentially with the shrinked label on top and a border.

Something like this would be enough:

[image]

(no need for the label to animate-shrink on focus, it can be shrinked by default)

I see the `Editable` component from `slate-react` has a `as` prop that takes a component as input.. but I cannot make it work by passing `BaseInput`..

I was thinking something like this would have worked:

```
<FormControl>
    <InputLabel shrink={true}>LABEL</InputLabel>
    <Slate ...>
       ...
       <Editable as={InputBase} />
    </Slate>
</FormControl>
```

But obviously it does not work.. any suggestion?